# Rsync incremental backups

Tags: python, shell, rsync

I try to configure a python script to run incremental backups but i think it doesnt work like it would be. Indeed, my incremental backup got the same size than the previous and same contents.
this is my ptyhon script juste below (and cmd = rsync -av --exclude backups/ --link-dest=/appli/jenkins/backups/jenkins_2021-06-10-10-43-25-274629/ --delete /appli/jenkins /appli/jenkins/backups/jenkins_2021-06-10-10-44-41-719596)

```
def incremental_backup():
source_dir = const.source_directory
backup_dir = const.target_directory
date_time = str(datetime.now()).replace(' ','-').replace(':','-').replace('.','-')
backup_path = backup_dir + "/jenkins_" + date_time
latest_link = backup_dir + "/jenkins_2021-06-10-10-27-37-787006/"

rsync_cmd = "rsync -av --exclude " + "backups/ --link-dest=" + latest_link + " --delete " + source_dir + " " + backup_path
# print(rsync_cmd)
os.system(rsync_cmd)
# os.system("rm -rf " + latest_link)
# os.system("mkdir /appli/jenkins/backups/latest")
# os.system("ln -s " + backup_path + " " + latest_link)
```

Moreover when I run for the first time it copy all data from source_dir, but when i run for a second or more time with latest_link option : console return just few file  copy with this message :
sent 3,665,723 bytes  received 30,840 bytes  672,102.36 bytes/sec
total size is 1,889,011,538  speedup is 511.02

So my incremental backup has the same size that the full backup, is it normal, if not could you help me to understand what is it wrong with my script please :)

INFO : rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31

Sorry for my english

Comment: May I ask, why not just write a shell script to handle this natively?  Why abstract the process using Python?

Comment: Yes it's a good question, I write the process using Python for a better understanding on my coworker, shell is not very readable for everyone :). The script is running with no problem, juste the backup took the same size as a full backup :/

Comment: I already try to run it in terminal but the results is the same, rsync copy the file in more but the backup has got the same size as full backup. :/ I see the difference when I run rsync, it shows me the file in more but copyu all files and I don't understand that :/

Comment: Do you why rsync with --link-dest backup not change files too please ?